# Tkinter win11 rounded window when using borderless

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, windows-11

On Windows 11 any Tkinter window will become rounded, but if I use `root.overrideredirect(True)` to make the window borderless, the window will not be rounded anymore.
I have seen some other methods of making the Tkinter window rounded but they all seem very complicated and all those methods are quite old, are there any new methods now that windows 11 has been out for quire a while?

I am using Python 3.10.8
I have gone thru all the release notes of the later 3.10 updates (3.10.9 thru 3.10.12) and none of them mention any Tkinter changes that may have fixed this.
Neither did any of the 3.11 release notes.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unspecific. Research more. Tcl/tk does not provide that feature. So you need to use the native Win32 API. There are multiple ways. Keywords are ```winfo_id()```, ```SetWindowsHookEx()```, ```WM_NCPAINT```, ```WM_ERASEBKGND```, ```DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()```, etc.

Comment: How do I need to research more? I went thru all the release notes of all python versions after the one I'm currently using, I have ofcourse googled it but the only methods I found where ways to do it that would require way too much effort. I did know it would probably have to do something with the windows api if I want to get the the result I want, but your comment doesn't really help. Would you be able to folow up with some actual help on how I would be able to achieve what I want?

Comment: As I said, you have to use the native Win32 API either by using the ```ctypes``` or by implementing a C extension module. I already gave keywords for Win32 API. It's not an easy task. Just google them and learn by yourself. You will find example codes by others, although they may not be in Python.